# Git reset my files when creating a new branch

Tags: git

I have a problem. I haven't been committing changes via git for a while, and now when I was trying to create a new branch and push my new version of the filesystem to this branch, my whole filesystem was changed to a version that is older. In other words: I need to get my newest version back again!

These are the exact commands that I ran:

```
git stash
git checkout -b log_branch
git push origin
git push --set-upstream origin log_branch
git add .
git push
git commit -m "new stuff"
git push
```

Please help me get my old files back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get your stashed changes back, apply them

```
git stash apply
```

FYI, you don't need to stash your changes in order to checkout a new branch, so you could have accomplished this by omitting the first line. Also, you might have extra pushes that aren't needed.

```
git checkout -b log_branch

git push --set-upstream origin log_branch
git add .

git commit -m "new stuff"
git push
```